# Stop regex search at optional pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to make a Regex pattern that can pull a few elements from an email. The email may or may not be forwarded. If it is not forwarded, it will match this format:

```
-match one
-match two
-match three
-and a bunch of notes here, potentially with more than 1 line or newlines included 
and there may be hyphens in this text as well
```

If it is forwarded, it will match this format:

```
-match one
-match two
-match three
-and a bunch of notes here, potentially with more than 1 line or newlines included 
and there may be hyphens in this text as well

---------- Forwarded message ----------
From:....
```

I'm having trouble making a pattern that will work for both cases and will capture everything between the 4th dash and the line that starts "------Forwarded...."

Here is the pattern I came up with as a placeholder: `\-\s?(.+)\s\-\s?(.+)\s\-\s?(.+)\s\-\s?([^[-]*)`. However, this does not work when the text after the 4th dash has hyphens in it because then it cuts off after it finds a hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be matching the 3 lines and only the dash of the fourth line. Then capture in a group all lines that do not start with a dash.

```
^(?:-.*\n){3}-((?:.*\n(?!-).*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:-.*\n){3}` Match 3 line and a newline (Use `(?:-.*\n)+` to match 1 or more lines)
- `-` Match the fourth dash
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:.*\n(?!-).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with a dash
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OuwFFz/1)

You can also exclude matching `---------- Forwarded message` if there can be no overlap

```
^(?:-.*\n){3}-((?:.*\n(?!-+ Forwarded message).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTKaIn/1)

But see [this example](https://regex101.com/r/gHA8aY/1) what all the matches can also be in that case.